# How to find the size of internal routing table efficiently?

Tags: networking, routing

I need to know how to find the size of the kernel routing table.
I have knowledge that the routing table is stored in `/proc/net/route`.

I am presently using the command `wc` to count the number of characters in this routing file. But the problem is my routing table will contains thousands of entries and I need to be able to find the size of it very frequently.

Is the size of the routing file stored elsewhere?
How do I get to know the size of the file `/proc/net/route` efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to using `/proc/net/route` for finding the number of route entries on your machine:

One can obtain this information by polling the machine's SNMP MIB table:

`snmpwalk -v 2c -c <YourSNMPString> <YourIPAddress> 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21`

```
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteDest.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteDest.169.254.0.0 = IpAddress: 169.254.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteDest.192.168.1.0 = IpAddress: 192.168.1.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: 2
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.169.254.0.0 = INTEGER: 2
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.192.168.1.0 = INTEGER: 2
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMetric1.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: 1
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMetric1.169.254.0.0 = INTEGER: 0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMetric1.192.168.1.0 = INTEGER: 0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteNextHop.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 192.168.1.1
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteNextHop.169.254.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteNextHop.192.168.1.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteType.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: indirect(4)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteType.169.254.0.0 = INTEGER: direct(3)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteType.192.168.1.0 = INTEGER: direct(3)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteProto.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: local(2)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteProto.169.254.0.0 = INTEGER: local(2)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteProto.192.168.1.0 = INTEGER: local(2)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMask.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMask.169.254.0.0 = IpAddress: 255.255.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMask.192.168.1.0 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteInfo.0.0.0.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteInfo.169.254.0.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteInfo.192.168.1.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
```

In the previous example, you will be interested in the last three lines of output.

Or, you could run the following command to obtain only the count of your system's routing table entries:

`snmpwalk -v 2c -c <YourSNMPString> <YourIPAddress> 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21 | grep  "ipRouteInfo" | wc -l` which will return a value of `3` in this particular case.

If you are more comfortable with a GUI interface for gathering this information, I would recommend using [SNMPb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpb/) to query your MIBs:

[image]

If one is interested in only looking at the route cache, and not simply the number of entries in your table, one can determine the size of the route cache with the following command:

`dmesg | grep -i 'IP route cache'`

This command should return output similar to the following:

`[0.213066] IP route cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)`

If one is looking for a time incremented count of the route cache *entries*, I would recommend using the following command:

`lnstat -s1 -i1 -c-1 -f rt_cache`

You can modify the the update interval as you see fit and then pipe the output to a file for easy manipulation (see also [Tuning Linux IPv4 route cache](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ipv4-route-cache-linux.html) for more details). The `rt_cache` entry column would be useful if you are maintaining a dynamic routing table on your machine and want to track the route table fluctuation(due to flapping, route withdrawal, etc).

This is based upon the default maximum size of the IPv4 and IPv6 tables, which  you can obtain by using the following command:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv{4,6}/route/max_size`

The default routing table size for IPv4 and IPv6 are 4096 and 524288, respectively.

Comment: I am actually looking for the number of entries in the table. So its precisely the size of the file /proc/net/route where the routing table is stored in memory.
As per my knowledge, this is the only place where we can find the kernel routing table. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jerald see updates above. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot maggotbrain. Yes the information you provided is very helpful. I just need the detail of the size and the number of entries. And I need to get these details on a periodic basis on routing tables which will have 10000s of entries. Your approach of using wc works but as I am doing it very often, it seems to be computationally expensive. Is there a way I can just access the size/no_of_entries without using the wc? (a less computationally expensive way)

Comment: @Jerald Excellent! I am glad to hear that. Feel free to accept my answer if you think it has answered your question.

Comment: @KevinBowen You totally did not answer the question asked. He is asking if he can just find out the # of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
route -n | wc
```

Subtract one from the returned value to account for your default route.